# WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) Ubuntu 18.04 LTS compile Tezos Node

Tags: node, windows

I've tried to compile a Tezos Node on a Windows 10 PC with WSL Ubuntu.

I've used [this](https://github.com/tezoscommunity/FAQ/blob/master/Compile_Mainnet.md) Guide.

If i try to do `make build-deps`, i am getting the following error: [Link](https://gist.github.com/Blindripper/234c871aa9a56ff33279cea6013a980f)

Comment: The error says `Curl failed` - do you have the `curl` command available on WSL?

Comment: Hi, yeah: `curl is already the newest version (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.2).`

Comment: `eval $(opam env)
opam update && opam upgrade` Didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall similar curl errors when building on older versions of ubuntu and debian. The solution there was to install a newer version of git. Look for references to "git" in https://github.com/tezoscommunity/FAQ/blob/master/Compile_Mainnet.md

Answer (score 0):

I tried getting Tezos building and running on different WSL's but there was always different issues coming up - building Tezos was fine but running Tezos was tricky.

You can install VirtualBox (which is free) and then install a official Linux distribution.

It will be emulated so it is slower but it works perfectly.

You can copy & paste txt between host (Windows 10) and guest machine (Linux) and it even supports file drag & drop.  Both of these features are life savers for development.